# Не загружаются команды из когов на disnake

Tags: python, disnake

У меня есть 2 файла, main.py (где происходит старт бота, и загружаются коги), и Store-message.py (сам ког). В каждом есть по 1 тестовой команде. Ошибок при старте бота никаких нет, и со временем тоже не появляются, однако слеш-команды загружаются только с основного файла (main.py).

```
import os
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

print("Начинаем...")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=None)
token = "он есть"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Бот запущен! \nTOKEN: {token}")

@bot.slash_command(description="Проверка когов")
async def cog_check1(inter, test: str):
    await inter.send(test)

bot.load_extensions("cogs")

bot.run(token)
```

Ког вроде-как запускается, т.к. в скрипте есть отправка сообщений (см ниже)

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

print("Ког1 начинает инициализацию")

class TestCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

        @commands.slash_command()
        async def test(self, inter, description="Тестовая команда, работает только на сервере"):
            await inter.send(f"Название сервера: {inter.guild.name}\nВсего участников: {inter.guild.member_count}")

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCommand(bot))
print("Ког1 загружен")
```